# Optimizing 300 append queries using separate table with criteria list and looping or cycling

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a process that currently requires 300 individual queries appended into one master table. Each query has the same structure, but different criteria for [Customer Name] and [Product Name]. I would like to optimize this database and ideally have 1 master query that references a table containing each query’s criteria. Something like this:
Criteria Table

[Query Name] | [Customer Name ]| [Product Name]

Criteria1 | Bob or Cindy | Hammers or Nails or Saws

Criteria2 | Bob or Jack | Screws or Bolts

…Criteria300

So the master query would run once, inputting from Criteria1 and filtering to only append results containing Bob or Cindy, Hammers or Nails or Saws. Once complete with Criteria 1, the process would ideally automatically continue to Criteria2, and so on until I get to Criteria300. 
I’m not very VBA savvy so I generally stick to writing queries using Design View. Is something like my above description possible? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the same structure from the two tables???

Ok, I would build a table with this structure:
[image]

So, you simply enter this into the table for the 300 criteria

Like this:

[image]

Note carefully, that we do enter quotes around each text part.

Now, in code we go:

```
Sub MyAppend()

  Dim strSQL        As String
  Dim strWhere      As String
  Dim rstCriteria   As DAO.Recordset
  
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyMaster " & _
           "SELECT * from SourceTable "
           
  Set rstCriteria = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSQL")
  
  Do While rstCriteria.EOF
     strWhere = "WHERE Person in (" & rstCriteria!PeopleList & ")" & _
     " AND PartName in (" & rstCriteria!PartsList & ")"
     
     Debug.Print "working on " & rstCriteria!ID
     
     CurrentDb.Execute strSQL & strWhere
     rstCriteria.MoveNext
  Loop
  rstCriteria.Close
  
  Beep
  MsgBox "done"
  
End Sub
```

The above is air code, but it should work.

## Edit

Start at a given step in the list

If you wanted to run say the last 50 out of 300, then you could go:

```
  strSQL = "select * from tblSQL where id >= 250 " & _
           "ORDER BY ID"
  Set rstCriteria = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: I'm on my way with this new code and am now wondering if there is a way I could tell it to start on a certain record? For example, if the process has already completed 200 queries and there is an interrupt, I would like to tell the code to start at query #201 instead of #001. Is this possible?

Comment: See my "edit" I added to the post - it will show you how to select a range, or start at any number in the list..